# Using assert in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is using Assert in Selenium a good thing?

Someone once suggested that using asserts slows down the test and I shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this would be the bottleneck of your tests. Waiting for the browser to render the web page, executing JavaScript and parsing and accessing the page via Selenium will outweigh the time needed for assertions by far.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Asserts` for my automated testcases in [Serenity](https://experitest.com/mobile-app-testing/working-with-serenity-bdd-framework-an-overview/), Selenium and [JBehave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development#Tooling_principles) and in my opinion it doesn't matter if you use Asserts, Exceptions or something else...

As Sebastian posted already, the time for opening, rendering pages and accessing the objects will outweigh the time needed for assertion way more. The only thing you can optimize is the loading speed of your page and how you access the web elements.

If you search for an XPath expression you should see that you can optimize your XPath expression for faster searching (e.g., not using //* to look into every node) or even better you use CSS or id selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Assert is to verify test output. More you limit asserts better it can get overload during test cases [Read this](http://selftechy.com/2011/07/10/selenium-use-assertions-to-verify-the-test-output)

Asserts are same overload for testing as comparisons in programming terms. Example is to use asserts to test values validations or filled in Form input that gets populated from grid to Edit/Update fields Just a simple example i can think of.